# inclusion functor of FinSet into Top

Tags: category-theory

I was reading [Codensity and Stone spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1370) by Andrei Sipos where the author defines an inclusion functor from FinSet to Top without (or perhaps I missed it) specifying the topological structure we would endow on finite sets. Does any one know if there is a canonical choice of topological structure associated with a given finite set?

Comment: The discrete topology is standard. It's the only Hausdorff one, at least.

Comment: Probably the discrete topology, but I can't say for sure

Comment: @anomaly thanks! The observation that only the discrete topology is helpful! Since the claim is the algebra category associated with the induced codensity monad given by the inclusion functor from FinSet into Top is the category of Stone spaces, the Hausdorff structure is probably necessary.

Comment: @Max thanks a lot!